# Problem on identical particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, identical-particles

**Question** : Two identical particles are described by the hamiltonian $$H=\frac{p_1^2(x_1)}{2m}+\frac{p_2^2(x_2)}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2x_1^2}{2}+\frac{m\omega^2x_2^2}{2}$$
Obtain the energy spectrum of the system and give it's degeneracy.

**My solution**: I tried solving it by separating out the hamiltonian of both the particles. Then we will get two separate equations of a linear harmonic oscillator for both particle-1 and particle-2, as follows
$$H(1)u_a(1)=E_au_a(1) $$ and, $$H(2)u_b(2)=E_bu_b(2)$$
where, $E_a=(n_1+\frac{1}{2})ħ\omega$ and $E_b=(n_2+\frac{1}{2})ħ\omega$ , are the energy eigenvalue for linear harmonic oscillator . Therfore the total energy of the system will be $$E=E_a+E_b=(n+1)ħ\omega$$ where $n=(n_1+n_2)$ =0,1,2,etc.

**To find the degeneracy:**

Let's suppose n=3 then I can have the following possible combinations.

$n_1$=0, $n_2$=3

$n_1$=1, $n_2$=2

$n_1$=2, $n_2$=1

$n_1$=3, $n_2$=0

Therfore, degeneracy=4 for n=3. In general, degeneracy =(n+1)

**My doubt** : Is my solution correct?

Comment: can we at least tell the user what is wrong with the post instead of down-voting to oblivion?  **yes, it seems low quality** - but; I would at least, tell what is wrong with the post first *at least*. We should encourage people to at least Know what was wrong, because there are many things in posts(questions,comments and answers) that can be wrong. :)

Comment: Is this from a book? and if so, what book?(and chapter if applicable.) As well as, did you try any post/references/other sources? if so, can you post them? :) Wishes from Sweden!

Comment: @WilliamMartens It's from Foundation of Quantum Mechanics by A.B. Gupta. The name of the chapter is "Multi-electron atoms". And I tried searching solutions in Google but didn't find any

Comment: +1 for fast reply!   thanks! will look into the book; hold on (edit this in the question to include the book and what you tried searching, but (as you point out) didn't find any)  :) `edit` is it this book? https://www.amazon.in/Quantum-Mechanics-Dr-S-L-Gupta/dp/B07CMWWY6K

Comment: @WilliamMartens The reason the post was closed can be seen. I don't know what a comment should add there.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Yes, I know but ; it can be a great thing to explain it in comments as well :) some(including me) people might think of many many different things when the reason is totally visible, im just trying to make it as "understandable" as possible.

Comment: @WilliamMartens Well, all of this is explained in the community guidelines and the close-reason contains links, too. And moreover, when asking a question, there are many links and again the homework policy is explained in a sidebar. If you want to leave a comment to elaborate that further, fine, do so.

Comment: thanks so much :) +1

Comment: @WilliamMartens no..its not that book. It's this one : https://www.amazon.in/Foundation-Quantum-Mechanics-3ed-Gupta/dp/8195318983/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?crid=3MYVBQRPZYT0A&keywords=quantum+mechanics+by+ab+gupta&qid=1673517523&sprefix=ab+gupta+qu%2Caps%2C453&sr=8-3

Comment: @user231188 oh thanks! thanks so much!